# Django Rest Framework @api_view(['POST])

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there way to return default content in function based **@api_view(['POST'])** Like a class based **generics.CreateAPIView**

[This is CreateApiView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYR8Y.png)

[This is result of CreateApiView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eltA0.png)

But when I used @api_view(['GET','POST']) result will be like this:

[This is my fbv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABXrH.png)

[This is result of fbv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgbPz.png)

I hope I can explain. In a nutshell, I need a default post content before posted using function based view

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def your_view(requset):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response({'some': 'data'})

    ...<your other POST logic here>...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Response, from rest_framework API
which will return in JSON format

e.g
from rest_framework.response import Response
return Response(data)

Comment: I have used Response but response return data when I post request but I need default json before posted.